Proving Green's formulas in Evans' PDE
Just as the title states. I have been away from math for several months now, and I was jumping into Evans PDE, but I wanted to cover all the appendices before I moved onto the actual book. It's possible that just the notation is confusing me, or I'm just a little tripped up. The part of the theorem I am trying to prove goes as follows
let $u,v \in C^2(\overline{U})$. Then
$$\int_U Dv \cdot Du \hspace{2mm} dx = - \int_U u\Delta v dx + \int_{\partial U} \frac{\partial u }{\partial\nu} u dS $$
Evans says to employ the following equation with $v_{x_i}$ replacing $v$
$$\int_U u \Delta v -v\Delta u \hspace{2mm} dx = \int_{\partial U} u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu}- v \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} dS$$
I think where I'm going wrong is in replacing $v$ with $v_{x_i}$ so this is what I had
$$\int_U u \Delta v -v_{x_i}\Delta u \hspace{2mm} dx = \int_{\partial U} u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu}- v_{x_i} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}dS$$
It would feel wrong to replace the $\Delta v$ with $\Delta v_{x_i}$ because $\Delta v = \sum_{I=1}^n v_{x_i x_i}$
Anyway from here we can rearrange the equation just a little bit and get that
$$- \int_U v_{x_i} \Delta u \hspace{2mm} dx = -\int_u u \Delta v\hspace{2mm} dx + \int_{\partial U} u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu} \hspace{2mm}dS - \int_{\partial U} v_{x_i} u_{x_i} \nu^i \hspace{2mm} dS$$
Now if we add over the last term on the RHS we have
$$\int_{\partial U} v_{x_i} u_{x_i} \nu^i \hspace{2mm} dS- \int_U v_{x_i} \Delta u \hspace{2mm} dx = -\int_u u \Delta v\hspace{2mm} dx + \int_{\partial U} u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu} \hspace{2mm}dS $$
Now the RHS is completely correct, but the left hand side is still wrong. I fiddled with for a bit but I was unable to get anywhere. What is the next step here? Again I have been away from math for months, and just want to get back into it.

You're getting confused with indices. When you use the free index $i$ in $v_{x_i}$ in the above equation, it is no longer sensible to write the Laplacian using $i$ as the index. You must use a different index, i.e, $\Delta v_{x_i}=\sum_j v_{x_ix_jx_j}$

Ah, so I do have the replace the $\Delta v_{x_i}$ that's not what I had done. I haven't had to deal with index notation in forever so seeing it again tripped me up just a little
